# Cannot execute shell commands in bash script

Tags: bash

```
 #!/bin/bash
#general security monitoring
PATH=/var/log
echo "The IP addresses of users with more than 2 failed login attempts are:"
IPFAILEDLOGINS=$(grep "Failed password" /var/log/secure | cut -d: -f4 | awk '{print $6}' | uniq -c | awk '{if ($1>=2) print $2}')
echo "$IPFAILEDLOGINS"

RSYSLOGCLIENTS=$(find /var/log -type d -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".*/([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+")
echo "The current rsyslog clients are: $RSYSLOGCLIENTS"
```

error: `./securityanalysis.sh: line 7: find: command not found`

find is located under /bin, which is included in my PATH. I also put the directory this script was being executed in into the PATH but it didn't make a difference.

Replacing the `echo..` line with `eval $RSYSLOGCLIENTS` also gave me the same error.

Can someone please explain what is happening?

Note: I assume this is extremely bad practice, but this script is located in the home directory of root. Could this have something to do with it?

Comment: Is this really your code?  It seems like something is missing which would generate such an error message.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I have posted the whole thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> find is located under /bin, which is included in my PATH

No, it isn't.  Your PATH is redefined in line 3 of the script to be:

```
PATH=/var/log
```

Observe that the `find` command works *before* but not *after* PATH is reassigned:

```
$ RSYSLOGCLIENTS=$(find /var/log -type d -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".*/([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+")
$ PATH=/var/log
$ RSYSLOGCLIENTS=$(find /var/log -type d -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".*/([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+")
bash: find: command not found
```

The general lesson here is, when defining shell variables for your script, *never* use all capitals.  The shell uses all caps for its important variables, like PATH.  You don't want to overwrite them.  Use lower or, at least, mixed case for your internal script variables.

For example, the `path` variable is assigned a value and it does not affect the ability of the shell to find `find`:

```
$ RSYSLOGCLIENTS=$(find /var/log -type d -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".*/([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+")
$ path=/var/log
$ RSYSLOGCLIENTS=$(find /var/log -type d -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".*/([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+")
$
```

In shell, variable names are case-sensitive and, therefore, `PATH` and `path` are separate and independent variables.